# List<T>.Find throwing System.IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, generics

I'm getting a System.IndexOutOfRangeException on List.Find(). The problem is that it is not consistent, and is happening only in the Production Environment. Going through the MSDN documentation for the [List.Find(Predicate match) method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0b5b5bc.aspx), but it does say about Index out of range exception. In what scenario would System.IndexOutOfRangeException be thrown from List.Find() method?

This is happening in an ASP.Net applications. The code is inside a static method like so:

```
private static T GetReflectionInfo<T>(object obj, string memberName) where T :    System.Reflection.MemberInfo
{
    var knownInfos = new List<MemberInfo>();
    /// populate the list
    /// this line is where the exception is thrown. T is the generic type passed in.
    T info = (T) knownInfos.Find(item => item is T && item.Name.EqualsIgnoreCase(memberName));
}
```

[Update] - the issue turned out to be something wrong with one of the nodes. Thanks for your answers and comments.

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: How is this list persisted? In a web environment, shared resources need special handling.

Comment: Are you using this in a multithreaded application?

Comment: @JaredPar: I read 'Production' somehow as 'ASP.NET'. Whoops :)

Answer (score 8):

It could be thrown if you are modifying the `List` (specifically removing items) from another thread while the Find is running.  As per [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx), that isn't allowed (emphasis mine):

> **Thread Safety**
>
> Public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this
> type are thread safe. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be
> thread safe.
>
> A List(Of T) can support multiple readers concurrently, ***as long as the
> collection is not modified***. Enumerating through a collection is
> intrinsically not a thread-safe procedure. In the rare case where an
> enumeration contends with one or more write accesses, the only way to
> ensure thread safety is to lock the collection during the entire
> enumeration. To allow the collection to be accessed by multiple
> threads for reading and writing, you must implement your own
> synchronization.